# What do I require to develop c# without using Visual Studio on Windows?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, terminal, ide, development-environment

I like using my own text editor for coding. I use terminal.  What do I need if I want to develop C# without using Visual Studio on Windows?

Comment: The [Compiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/command-line-building-with-csc-exe) (if you want to compile... *writing* doesn't need *anything*)? Anything else is "just" for convenience.

Comment: Why don't you want to use Visual Studio? [Its Free!](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/)

Comment: Do yourself a favour, use the best IDE on the planet.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your reasons are for only developing with a text editor and a command line interface, but I think that you should reconsider.

An IDE is not only for editing and compiling the software, but also for debugging it as well. I am a pretty decent software developer, but even I find that debugging code without a proper debugger is next to impossible.

I once taught as a lab assistant in a university. The students were learning Java and their IDE was BlueJ. But there was one person who had the source code in Notepad and was compiling and running the software through the command line.

Whenever something went wrong - and something usually goes wrong, whether you're a beginner or a senior developer - he'd take the line number from the stack trace and look for it in Notepad. Notepad doesn't have line numbers, so he had line numbers in comments at the start of each line. Of course, when he changed something, he would have to update the line numbers. And every second line in his code was `System.Out.Println`.

I did try to figure out what was the issue, but I couldn't. Without a proper debugger, finding and fixing errors in software will take twenty times longer than with a good IDE. And in my opinion Visual Studio is a very good IDE.

Comment: The problem was the guy didn't know how to debug.  I've trained heaps of Devs and a lot didn't know the core features of what makes an IDE so powerful. Shame really.

Comment: The problem with my student - not the person asking this question - is that he didn't _want_ to learn how to use an IDE. I asked him why he wasn't using BlueJ and he said that it was because when he left college and went to a company he'd have to learn how to use a new IDE, so he didn't want to learn how to use a different one now. I tried not to be judgemental - after all, you're supposed to have knowledge coming out of a university, not going in - but after trying several times to understand what was wrong with his code I just told him to use BlueJ and left him at that.

Answer (score 1):

OK, Visual Studio 20xx is *big*, but at least check out [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) before punishing yourself with Terminal.